# Select * return empty cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I insert a record to my table. It success because .insert() return new row id which I use that id to query with where cause _id = id. **IT SUCCESS I GOT ROW RETURN**

But when I query with SELECT * FROM TABLE (no where cause) it return empty cursor!

please help me solve this problem

Here is insert method

```
public String insertCategory(String name, int color) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    cv.put(COLUMN_COLOR, color);

    long id;
    try {
        id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_CATEGORIES, null, cv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    Cursor row = getRowById(db, TABLE_CATEGORIES, id, new String[] {
            COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME });
    if (row.getCount() > 0) {
        if (row.moveToNext()) {
            return row.getString(row.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
        } else
            return null;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Here is method which I use to query with where cause

```
private Cursor getRowById(SQLiteDatabase db, String table, long id,
        String[] columns) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { "" + id }, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Finally, here is method which I use for query all row

```
public Cursor getAllCategories() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CATEGORIES, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

Thank you for all help

Comment: Oh I solve my problem by myself. problem of method getAllCategories() because I call db.close(); then I can't use my cursor after that.